# Is chopping used for the the most precise voltmeters?

Tags: analog, noise, input

Are the most precise nanovoltmeters (e.g., Keithley 2182A) for 1 Hz sampling (i.e.,
measuring the average over each second) chopping the input stage?
I can't tell from datasheets and am curious how they seem to avoid [flicker noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_noise).

My definition of "chopping" might be important, so let me rephrase the above question.
What frequency is the input stage's gate (or pick any one gate if some parallel
input mux scheme is being used) getting connected to the input voltage when I do
a 1 Hz sampling of a DC input voltage?  0 Hz indicates that no chopping is being done.

Comment: WIthout current (and hopefully, the Keithley doesn't require any worth considering) many sources of noise go away. Shot noise is gone. 1/f may be greatly reduced, as well. This pretty much leaves 4kTBR noise (Johnson/Nyquist.) You may be able to use that formula to get a bead on how they do things. For example, at ambient and 50 Ohms and 1 Hz I find about 1 nV RMS noise.

Comment: @jonk Yes, I know it's easy to get low 1nV noise if you ignore the 1/f noise.  You wrote "1/f may be greatly reduced", but it should not be reduced.  Anyway, I'm wondering whether Keithley chops the input or instead uses something like an input JFET to get the noise down.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much all multimeters (even the cheap handheld meters) use 'chopping' in the sense that they make a zero measurement and reference measurements as part of the measurement cycle.

The front end block diagram of the 2182 looks like this (image from [here](https://xdevs.com/fix/kei2182/)):

[image]

So, it's "chopping" into a low noise dual JFET front and amplifier, probably run at relatively high current. There is no information on the switching frequency. It's possible (likely, I think) that they take many measurements and filter them using the M68000 MCU and FPGA in order to reduce the RMS noise. The Q624 + U614 is going to be fairly drifty (maybe tens of Hz noise corner) so I don't think they are going to be doing a single measurement at 1Hz. It's not a "chopper amplifier", rather the input is switched between shorted, REF and input.

The primary reference is apparently a selected 0.5ppm LM399.

There are some photos of the low-noise preamplifier at the link above. The block diagram may be a bit simplified (maybe several JFET pairs in parallel to reduce the noise, and they are probably selected for low noise).

Comment: I think the conventional term I have seen used through several sources for "interleave dut and ref measurement" is *Auto Zero*

Comment: @tobalt Yes, that's the conventional term. The effect is the same- to move the measurement above the noise corner frequency (though we'd probably call the very low frequency noise "drift").

Comment: Personally, I discriminate between the two terms. AutoZero raises wideband noise so is only situationally useful. As "Chopping" i usually interpret input polarity inversion, which doesn't increase wideband voltage noise but increases input current. Yes... I am aware that this is probably a pretty arbitrary definition, but it is based on what I believe most people mean when using the two terms. (E.g. for sure, also auto zeroing "chops" the input signal) Anyway if you wish, I will remove the semantics comments. +1 Anyway for the schematics alone :)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany From that schematic alone, the mux chopping/switching could be just a simple 1 Hz "Auto Zero", but, I agree, the mux is probably chopping at a much higher frequency than 1 Hz.  When the input is, for example, just 50nV, I'm still struggling to plot what each of the two Q624 gates are doing - Are they switching between 0nV, 50nV, and some high reference (like 1mV) at like 1 kHz?  Your answer would be perfect if it could add these details, especially the frequency.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure low level DC then answer is definitely yes. An amplifier with no chopping has 1/f noise which can grow by the power law from the 10s of Hz range and then as you get close to DC. The only well I'm aware of to get around this is to chop DC to a higher frequency where only white noise exists and then filter it back down to DC. The most precise amplifiers all chop, such as the ADA4528 or A22 and A10 from EM electronics (the A10 can get into the pV range)

The nano voltmeters from keithley use a dual or single slope ADC as thier secret sauce (if I remember right), but they aren't the 'best you can do'. The enemy of the Keithley nanovoltmeters is 60 hertz noise which I believe the sloped ADC integrating time is tuned to that cycle to average out that noise (if I remember right you can also use an external trigger and choose your own integrating time)

Comment: Note that achieving a low base resolution such as picovolts is not causally related to achieving a large dynamic range such as 8 digits. Chopping indeed helps with the former by eliminating the input gain stage 1/f noise. It doesn't help with the latter which is fundamentally limited by the 1/f noise of the voltage reference.

Comment: Okay, I've used mechanical chopping in some instrument designs, so more general. Jones refers to chopping in his (then top-secret) mid-1930s wartime work on IR sensing. <10nW noise floor (1s), pretty good for 1930s.

Comment: Are you sure the A10 is chopping?  I see no evidence of this in [EM's online description/spec](https://www.emelectronics.co.uk/ultra-low-level-dc-voltage-amplifiers/dc-nanovolt-amplifier-model-a10/), so hoping you can give a reference.  I'd even like to know the frequency/duty/mux details for the chop.

Comment: @bobuhito Yeah, I've taken one apart, I can't remember the frequency off the top of my head. They use magnetic amplifiers and witchcraft to reconstruct the signal.

Answer (score 0):

I **believe 'no'** (i.e. not unconditionally*) because there is no need in order to achieve 8.5 digit resolution at 1 Hz. The main 1/f noise contributions are likely the input transistor and the LTZ1000.

When powering the input transistor at a typical 30 V supply, you need 1/f noise of better than 100 nV/rtHz at 1 Hz. This is easy for unchopped BJT or JFET input stages.

The LTZ consequently is the bottleneck. And you anyway cannot chop away its 1/f noise.

**(*)** Nevertheless most reasonable multimeters over an optional "Autozero" Mode which uses every other sample to renull the voltmeter offset. But as explained its use is situational:

When using a large input stage gain like 100x in the smaller ranges, the input transistor 1/f noise could eventually increase over the reference noise and therefore the AutoZero mode is useful in high gain ranges.

In contrast to actual chopping (i.e. inverting input polarity), Auto Zeroing techniques have the disadvantage of raising the wideband noise by \$\sqrt 2\$. Therefore, it should not be always on but is an option.

Comment: I agree that they might have a low-noise "BJT or JFET input", and therefore don't need to chop (but want to point out that the noise spec is stricter than your assumed 100nV; Keithley specs 15nV).  But, even if the spec is easy, why don't they then chop to improve the spec further?  I'm still hoping somebody might be familiar with the insides of these nanovoltmeters to avoid this speculation...

Comment: @bobuhito As I said you can't improve the 1/f spec by chopping the input if the bottleneck is the reference noise (which won't go away via chopping)